# Connecting Next.js to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, next.js

I have a fresh WordPress site set up on InMotion. I want to limit WordPress to the backend in terms of storing content and serving it via its API. I want to use Next.JS/React for the front end. My problem is that I am unsure how to connect the two.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or provide advice on how I can install Next.JS in my site files? Where should Next.JS and its JS files reside? Once installed how can I have my Next.JS javascript files become the theme for my WordPress installation? I have searched the net but there is scant information on these questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Basically you fetch data from the WordPress API (REST or GraphQL) to your Next.js or other React web application.

I recommend to not mix source code of both things - the React web app would be separate project, it is integrated with WordPress just through the API.

If you google "next.js wordpress" then you would find a few things:

- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/search?q=wordpress&type=Issues
- a few mentions of WordPress in this issue: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/727
- https://react-etc.net/entry/graphql-and-next-js-for-building-wordpress-sites-with-react-js
- https://medium.com/@proposalpaul/next-js-3-0-headless-wordpress-in-production-a-deep-review-e9758d29c212

Comment: He has not understood how javascript works, so mentioning GatsbyJS is not useful